# Flex : What the use of Drag Source for drag and drop?

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex4

I have already read about what is Drag Source in http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfe.html

However I still don't understand why u need this. Most of the example I have seen online, don't even use the drag source.I don't see the point of checking its format value in the  dragEnterHandler when u can straight away call DragManager.acceptDragDrop() for that target component. And every time I call mouseMoveHandler its going to set the same value to the  format string. Which means the format value will always be the same.

I feel I am not getting the concept right. Can some one pls help me with these questions and help me to understand.

So my questions to you:

1. why do we need drag source ?
2. Why some programs don't use drag source ?
3. What is the benefit using drag source ?
4. When must you drag source ?
5. Is it good not to use drag source ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I used DragSource as a data carried. Like in case you need to transport some data from the drag initiation point to the dragdrop handler, it can be done using the DragSource.

It can also be used as flag. Like if e.dragSource.hasFormat(a) do this else do that.